# Random Forest online/incremental learning in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, train

Is there a Random Forest implementation available in R, that supports online learning?

My alternative approach was to use the popular randomForest package and combine Random Forests (the existing one and the new one trained with the new data) to implement a simple online-learning approach. But therefore I have to remove trees from the random forest, so my second question is:

Can I somehow remove trees from an existing random forest in R?

Comment: If you are using Java then MOA could be usefull. MOA is a data mining environment for online learning. It supports ao. Hoeffding trees for streaming data. It is open source and related to Weka.

Comment: Thanks, yes i have heard about it, but I am looking for a R implementation for online learning...